# What would happen if I don´t add some activities in the manifest file?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have noticed that my app is working fine and I have many activities that are not in the manifest file, why is this possible?

Comment: If they are your activities, then apparently you are not starting them. If they are activities from libraries, those libraries might be contributing manifest entries for them into your merged manifest.

Comment: As a general rule, if an activity isn’t listed in the Manifest, then it won’t be seen by the Android system, and will never run. Can you upload the content of you Android Manifest ?

Comment: @CommonsWare let's see if I have understood, so if an activity is not  linked with a layout (it won´t be seen by the user then), it is not neccesary to add it in the manifest, right?

Comment: If you never call `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()` with an `Intent` that points at the activity, then the activity should never be used. Do **not** create classes that extend `Activity` (or `AppCompatActivity`, etc.) unless you intend to use them via `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`, or unless they are base classes for other activities that *will* be used with `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`. Most of the methods that you inherit from `Activity` will not work unless that activity is started with `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, but in reponse to my question, if an activity is not beeing used with intent so that it means that most probably that activity is not linked with a layout, it is not necessary to add it to the manifest file. I have noticed that when I delete one activity (that is being intented) from the manifest file, when that intent to that activity is done, the app crashes. Why does it crash?

Comment: "if an activity is not beeing used with intent so that it means that most probably that activity is not linked with a layout, it is not necessary to add it to the manifest file" -- that should not be an activity, then. "Why does it crash?" -- activities need to be registered in the manifest to teach Android the rules for who is allowed to start those activities and how they should be used.

Comment: @CommonsWare so in short words, if my app does not crash, it means that I have put in the manifest the right activities. Is that okay?

Comment: That depends entirely on your definition of "okay".

Comment: @CommonsWare well, I have just understood, all the activities should be in the manifest file becuase if the app does not crash with an activity that is not set in the manifest is because that activity shouldn´t been an activity In fact.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable summary.